# How do I correctly import my auth class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created my own auth 'AuthOnPostOnly, but I am having trouble correctly importing it.

note: I created an app called 'api'.  also left out **init**.py from all directories in this example but they are all there.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pipeline.apps.PipelineConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # for testing
    'django_nose',
    # thirdparty app
    'bootstrap3',
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap_pagination',
    'mobilereports',
    'rest_framework',
    'api'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'api.permissions.AuthOnPostOnly',
    )
}
```

directory structure

```
/proj
  /api
    urls.py
    views.py
    serializers.py
    /permissions
      permissions.py
  /proj
    /settings.py
    /urls.py
```

error:

```
Could not import 'api.permissions.AuthOnPostOnly' for API setting 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES'. AttributeError: module 'api.permissions' has no attribute 'AuthOnPostOnly'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you import it from within the permission's **init**.py, you might need to nest the AuthOnPostOnly class one level deeper:

```
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'api.permissions.permissions.AuthOnPostOnly',
    )
}
```

If that doesn't help, mind posting the contents of your **init**.py that exists on the same level as permissions.py, and also the contents of permissions.py itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. Change the import to:

   ```
   'api.permissions.permissions.AuthOnPostOnly'
   ```
2. Delete the `permissions` folder and make the `permissions.py` file be inside the `api` folder.
3. If you want to keep the `permissions` folder and `api.permissions.AuthOnPostOnly`, in `permissions/__init__.py` do:

   ```
   from api.permissions.permissions import AuthOnPostOnly
   ```